# How to stop bullet images from showing behind share buttons?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

On a Wordpress website I’m using Sharedaddy/Jetpack to show social share buttons underneath blogposts, which uses bullets to show the buttons. The bullets itself are hidden with with `list-style:none`.

On this website however, bullets are per stylesheet replaced by images and this causes the bullets to show behind the social buttons anyway.

The sharing buttons are placed in a `div` with `class="sharedaddy sd-sharing-enabled"`, so to hide the image bullets, I’ve tried adding to this to my stylesheet:

```
.sharedaddy ul li {
background: none;
}
```

But to no avail.

Does anyone know what I should do to stop the bullet images from showing behind the sharing buttons?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: is your site online? have a looking will help.

Comment: Thanks Paulie_D. I've tried to keep the code posted in the question as short as possible, and to provide only information that might be necessary to answer the question. If an answers will prove any code to be unnecessary anyway, I'll remove it from the question.

Answer (score 0):

Your theme or whatever framework you're using may be utilizing "list-style-image". If that's the case then you can fix it by:

```
list-style-image: none;
```